# How to solve crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff2384c4e1)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-big-sur

I've been developing my MacOS app on OS 10.14~10.15.7 and Xcode 11.3.1.
Recently I upgrade my OS version to 11.0.1 but keep Xcode version the same.

Run my app I will encounter following exception:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff2384c4e1)
```

When I type cmd in lldb:

```
image lookup -va 0x7fff2384c4e1
```

It shows following information:

```
Summary: AppKit`_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_NSSeparatorToolbarItemView + 49
    Module: file = "/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit", arch = "x86_64"
    Symbol: id = {0x0000f500}, range = [0x00007fff2384c4b0-0x00007fff2384c5c0), mangled="_OBJC_$_INSTANCE_METHODS_NSSeparatorToolbarItemView"
```

And I found if I go to "Edit Scheme" -> "Run" tab -> "info" tab -> uncheck "Debug executable"
AP will launch normally.

Does someone know how to resolve this issue?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to build your app with newer Xcode? There are many way to accomplish this but all tricky. The better way, as I do, is to have a virtualized Mac and try.